# java code not working as I am expecting

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, storage

I am really struggling on getting my java code to work. I have coded a program which determines what grade each score will get once entered in by the user and also finds the largest and smallest score. The program successfully figures out which score belongs in which grade but once I implement the piece of code which tries to find the largest number out of the scores it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure what it is!

here is the code...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grade
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
        int Agrade=0; //different variables used throughout the code
        int Bgrade=0;
        int Cgrade=0;
        int Dgrade=0;
        int Fgrade=0;
        int count=0;




    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   //name of Scanner 

    System.out.println("Please enter the exam grades one after the other ");
    System.out.println("Please enter a negative number at the end of the grade list to control the flow and then press enter :");
    int score = in.nextInt(); //stores numbers inputted

    System.out.println("Please enter the grades again for the largest number: ");
    double largest = in.nextDouble();


    while (in.hasNextDouble()){
       double input = in.nextDouble();
       if (input > largest) {
          largest = input;
       }
    }



 while(score>0)   //start while loop
     {
       count++;
 if(score>=70 && score<=100)
        Agrade++;
    else if(score>=60 && score<=69)
        Bgrade++;
    else if(score>=50 && score<=59)
        Cgrade++;
    else if(score>=40 && score<=49)
        Dgrade++;
    else if(score>=0 && score<=39)
        Fgrade++;
    score = in.nextInt();
 } //end while



 System.out.println("Total number of grades :"+ count);
 System.out.println("The largest number :"+ largest);
 System.out.println("The number of As :"+ Agrade);
 System.out.println("The number of Bs :"+ Bgrade);
 System.out.println("The number of Cs :"+ Cgrade);
 System.out.println("The number of Ds :"+ Dgrade);
 System.out.println("The number of Fs :"+ Fgrade);

 } // end main
} // end class
```

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by **it doesn't seem to work**

Comment: Also, see [Java variable naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), try not to start variables with caps.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably an exercise so will give just the idea.
Your while loop seems to be fine, just declare two variables before it.
one for holding the max grade initialized with lowest number and another for min grade with highest number.

`score = in.nextInt();` do

```
if ( score > highest  ) { highest = score;}
if ( score < lowest ) { lowest = score }
```

good luck.

Comment: For the OP benefit `lowest number == Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you are declaring the variable `input` every time the while loop runs. Instead, declare the variable like this:

```
double input;
```

and do it before the while loop. Then in the while loop replace that line with:

```
input = in.nextDouble();
```

If this isn't the problem, it might be how you've laid out the code. The second while loop, which begins with `while (score>0)` should be where you have the line `int score = in.nextInt()` Putting this after the first while loop means that it's executed after that while loop.

As a side note, common variables like `Agrade` should be written in camelCase, in which the first letter is lowercase and the letter of the next word is uppercase. This would make your variables

```
int aGrade = 0;
int bGrade = 0;
```

and so on. This is just proper form and shouldn't effect your program. Also, you should probably declare score and input at the top of your program since you use them in loops. This is also good form and organization. It would look like this:

```
int score;
double input;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check comments on code to understanding.

### MainClass:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grade
{
    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        /**
         * This gradesCount represent the A,B,C,D,E,F counts
         */
        int[] gradesCount = {0,0,0,0,0,0}; 
        double inputScore = 0;  
        double bestScore = 0;
        int total = 0;

        @SuppressWarnings ( "resource" )
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ( "If you want to end, enter a negative number" );
        System.out.print("Enter score: ");

        do
        {
            inputScore = in.nextDouble ( );
            //validation for the first iteration
            if(inputScore < 0 || inputScore > 100) break;
            System.out.print("Enter score: ");
            //Add to corresponding grade count
            if(inputScore>=70 && inputScore<=100) gradesCount[0]++;
            if(inputScore>=60 && inputScore<=69) gradesCount[1]++;
            if(inputScore>=50 && inputScore<=59) gradesCount[2]++;
            if(inputScore>=40 && inputScore<=49) gradesCount[3]++;
            if(inputScore>=0 && inputScore<=39) gradesCount[4]++;
            //Add one to total
            total++;
            //check best score
            if(inputScore > bestScore) bestScore = inputScore;
        }//This pattern check if its number between 0-100
        while ( in.hasNext ( "[0-9][0-9]?|100" ) );



        System.out.println ( "Negative number or not valid input. Exited." );

        System.out.println("Total number of grades :"+ total);
        System.out.println("The best score :"+ bestScore);
        System.out.println("The number of As :"+ gradesCount[0]);
        System.out.println("The number of Bs :"+ gradesCount[1]);
        System.out.println("The number of Cs :"+ gradesCount[2]);
        System.out.println("The number of Ds :"+ gradesCount[3]);
        System.out.println("The number of Fs :"+ gradesCount[4]);


    } 
}
```

### Input/Output:

```
If you want to end, enter a negative number
Enter score: 5
Enter score: 10
Enter score: 15
Enter score: 20
Enter score: 33
Enter score: 99
Enter score: 100
Enter score: 44
Enter score: -3
Negative number or not valid input. Exited.
Total number of grades :8
The best score :100.0
The number of As :2
The number of Bs :0
The number of Cs :0
The number of Ds :1
The number of Fs :5
```

### Documentation:

- [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
- [The while and do-while statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) (used for iteration)
- [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (used in do-while)